# Delphi 10.2 FTP SSL

Tags: delphi, ssl, ftp, indy, delphi-10.2-tokyo

Here's my program

```
ftp := TIdFTp.Create();
IdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL1 := TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL.Create(ftp);
with IdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL1 do
begin
    host := fhost;
    MaxLineAction := maException;
    port := 2111;
    ReadTimeout := 60000;
    SSLOptions.Method := sslvSSLv3;
    SSLOptions.Mode := sslmUnassigned;
end;
ftp := TIdFTp.Create();
with ftp do
begin
    Host := fHost;
    password := fpass;
    Username := fuser;
    IOHandler :=IdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL1;
    UseTLS := utUseExplicitTLS;
    DataPortProtection := ftpdpsPrivate;
    port := 2111;
end;
ftp.Connect;
```

I'm using `TIdFTP` component in Delphi 2007 and Delphi 10.2 Berlin.

For Delphi 2007, the program connects to FTP. However, for the Delphi 10.2 the program gives an error 'Could not load SSL library.'

In both cases, to the exe file directory I include the `ssleay32.dll` and `libeay32.dll` files

Comment: Do both programs use the same version of Indy (10.6.2) and the same pair of OpenSSL DLLs?

Comment: You don't need to set most of those `IOHandler` properties manually, they are already defaulted or set for you. Just set the `SSLOptions` values as needed. That being said, when you get a "could not load SSL library" error, you can call Indy's `WhichFailedToLoad()` function in the `IdSSLOpenSSLHeaders` unit to find out why it failed. Make sure you are using up-to-date OpenSSL DLLs, which you can get from http://indy.fulgan.com/SSL/

Comment: I uploaded the latest dll and it works. Thanks